# Include external code into angular project

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to include some external code to an angular project I started working recently. I would like to add this confetti animation to the project

http://jsfiddle.net/vxP5q/61/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=vxP5q

```
I created a route for the page I need to create in app.js
  $stateProvider.state('result', {
    url: '/result',
    templateUrl: 'templates/result_election.html',
    controller: 'ElectionCtrl'
  })
```

As this page is linked to the ElectionCtrl I inserted the code from the fiddle into the ElectionCtrl but it doesnt seem to have any effect on my page. The fiddle code is included inside this :

```
angular.module('election',[]).controller('ElectionCtrl', function($http, $scope, $ionicPopup, $localStorage, $location, $stateParams ,$ionicLoading){})
```

Comment: yes, is there a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The code you linked is just standard JavaScript that looks for a `<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>` and inserts the animation, on `$(document).ready`.  In order to use this in an angular partial, a few things need to happen.

First, the partial template `'templates/result_election.html'` would need to have the `canvas` element.

Secondly, the code in `$(document.ready)` would need to be moved into a function that can be called in `$stateChangeSuccess` from `ui-router`, since the `canvas` must be present on the page for the function to find it.

A more advanced form of this would be creating a directive which contains the template and the code to be executed in the `$compile` phase of the directive.